# Блокировать сайты попавшие на вебсервере в бан

Tags: firewall, freebsd, mysql

Нужно блокировать сайты попавшие на вебсервере в бан [храниться в mysql ip)Как  закинуть их  в pf.conf он умеет принимать массивы ? или запросы из mysql ?Серваки freebsd 8,2, 9.0 9.2

Answer (score 1):

Можно по cron-у запускать скрипт который будет дампать из базы список IP и добавлять в фаервол соответствующие правила. Только нужно как-то обеспечить что-бы каждый раз не создавались дубликаты правил. Например можно при каждом запуске удалять все правила ранее созданные этим скриптом (нужно их как-то выделять) и добавлять новый (обновлённый набор), или получать разницу между тем что есть и тем что должно быть. В Linux есть фича ipset, набор ip-адресов (или подсетей) на который можно ссылаться в правилах фаервола, можно добавлять IPы в него (на сколько я помню в ipset не может дважды храниться один и тот-же ip). Думаю во FreeBSD должно быть что-то подобное.

Comment: Да то блокировать , скриптом пересоздавать список это не сложно, вот я думал PF  умеет чтото с напрямую с БД